# react component nested array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am new to react and I am having some trouble mapping nested array of objects in my app as it comes as undefined.

This is my api response which is an array of recipes.

```
const recipeMock = [
{
    "ingredientsInfo": [
        {
            "ingredientId": {
                "_id": "609e1325f5bbf3301d24102c",
                "name": "spaghetti squash",
            },
            "gramsPerIngredient": 301
        },
        {
            "ingredientId": {
                "_id": "609e1325f5bbf3301d24102b",
                "name": "spaghetti squash",
            },
            "gramsPerIngredient": 47
        },
    ],
    "_id": "609e1326f5bbf3301d241242",
    "name": "pain de mie",
    "gramsPerRecipe": 223,
    "elabTime": 20,
    "carbs": 201,
    "proteins": 10,
    "calories": 605,
        "instructions": "hi",
        "picture": "https://unsplash.com/photos/ijlUGGnrZsI",
    },{...other recipes following same structure
}]
```

I have created a component which paints each recipe that is the following:

```
export default function RecipeCard({
  recipeId,
  recipeName,
  ingredientsInfo,
  elabTime,
  carbs,
  proteins,
  calories,
  instructions,
  picture,
  addRecipeToUser,
})
```

which in return renders a card. But trouble comes when mapping `ingredientsInfo` as follows:

```
   <div className="recipeCard_ingredients">
    <ul className="recipeCard_ingredients_list">
      {ingredientsInfo.map((ingredient, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          <Link to={`/ingredients/${ingredient.ingredientId.name}`}>
            {ingredient.ingredientId.name}
          </Link>
          <p>{ingredient.gramsPerIngredient} grams</p>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

The console tells me "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

Comment: can you show where do you fetch the data and how do you store it ? This is probably due to asychronous api call

Comment: Could be many reasons.. impossible to tell unless you show a more complete code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` will be encountered if there is an error in the `ingredientsInfo` or `ingredientsInfo` there is no array.

Better put condition to check the the array like:

```
<div className="recipeCard_ingredients">
<ul className="recipeCard_ingredients_list">
  {ingredientsInfo && ingredientsInfo.map((ingredient, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
      <Link to={`/ingredients/${ingredient.ingredientId.name}`}>
        {ingredient.ingredientId.name}
      </Link>
      <p>{ingredient.gramsPerIngredient} grams</p>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine although ingredientsInfo will always be populated so i dont really know why it turns undefined, maybe it tries to map it before initialization. Anyway, thanks a lot, that was just the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, and the mock, you have used:

```
<RecipeCard {...recipeMock} />
```

Instead of:

```
<RecipeCard {...recipeMock[0]} />
```

If you insist to use without index then make sure to map it first and then only map `ingredientsInfo` inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `RecipeCard` function mustn't receive the `recipeMock` object as its parameters. In React, function parameters are used to pass props from other components.

Secondly, you have to map over `recipeMock` before you can access `ingredientsInfo`, since both are arrays. This means you have to nest two map functions like so:

```js
const recipeMock = [
  {
    ingredientsInfo: [
      {
        ingredientId: {
          _id: "609e1325f5bbf3301d24102c",
          name: "spaghetti squash"
        },
        gramsPerIngredient: 301
      },
      {
        ingredientId: {
          _id: "609e1325f5bbf3301d24102b",
          name: "spaghetti squash"
        },
        gramsPerIngredient: 47
      }
    ],
    _id: "609e1326f5bbf3301d241242",
  }
];
```

```js
const RecipeCard = () => {
  return recipeMock.map(({ ingredientsInfo, _id }) => (
    <div key={_id}>
      {ingredientsInfo.map(
        ({ gramsPerIngredient, ingredientId: { _id, name } }) => (
          <p key={_id}>
            {gramsPerIngredient}, {name}
          </p>
        )
      )}
    </div>
  ));
};
```

Here's a working demo in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/bold-gauss-z5n05?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: Thanks! yes, I mapped recipesMock and ingredients, but just ingredientsInfo was returning undefined, so I just added this part to the question, thanks! I solved it following above answer.